# What to do if I need a disposable object to stay present until my console application has ended?

Tags: c#, timer, dispose, idisposable

I have read a couple of threads asking this question but that involve Windows Forms applications. Forms applications have functions that are called when they are closed, which makes it easy to dispose of objects on application termination. I have an event-based console application that will be continuously running in the system's background similar to a service. The only way to end the program will be to end the process through the task manager. I accomplished this by calling Console.Read after all logic in main() and hiding the console so that it runs indefinitely.

I have a Timer object that I want to make sure gets disposed of, but since there is no official exit to my program, I do not know where to dispose of it. Would it be okay to let the operating system dispose of it since only a single class depends on it? I have read that it is dangerous to override the finalize() function, and don't want to do anything too tricky. There will only be one instance of my application running over long periods of time (until the system shuts off or until I push out an update).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but Garbage Collection should take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are killing the process, there isn't any code where you could dispose the timer, but you don't need to worry about it.

When the process is stopped, everything in its memory space goes away. The process runs in a separate virtual memory space, and that entire memory space is removed when the process is stopped.